# set::key_comp vs set::value_comp in C++?

Tags: c++, performance, stl, std, stdset

What is the difference between **set::key_comp** vs **set::value_comp** in **C++**? Going to cplusplus.com page there is no significant difference.
Furthermore on set::key_comp & related set::value_comp pages
last sentence is "(...) key_comp and its sibling member function value_comp are equivalent."

Examples are almost the same:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/key_comp/

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/value_comp/

Comment: They're the same also better to use [cpp reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) rather than cplusplus IMO. see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/value_comp and http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/key_comp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`key_comp` defines the order of the *keys* in a container.

`value_comp` defines the order of the *values* in a container.

In a `std::set` where, essentially, the values are the keys, the two are indeed exactly equivalent. But that's not true in all containers, e.g. `std::map`, or, in general, in a container that you might build yourself that follows the conventions of the C++ Standard Library Containers.

Note also that http://en.cppreference.com/w/ is a superior reference for C++. It pretty much proxies the standards.

Answer (score 3):

These are identical, both must be made available by any implementation because [`std::set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) must meet the requirement of [Associative Container](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/AssociativeContainer).

This allows you to write generic code that works with any *Associative Container* (`std::set`, `std::map`, `std::multiset`, `std::multimap` in the standard library).

Answer (score 1):

The difference comes when `key` and `value` are different entities inside a container.

For containers like `set`, these two terms mean same thing.

While, for containers like `map` or `multimap`, the `key` and `value` are separate entities maintained as an single entry.

Here is an example which shows how they differ:

```
std::set<int> myset;
int highest1, highest2, highest3;
typedef map<int, int> MyMap;
MyMap mymap;

std::set<int>::key_compare   myCompKeyForSet = myset.key_comp();
std::set<int>::value_compare myCompValForSet = myset.value_comp();

MyMap::key_compare   myCompKeyForMap = mymap.key_comp();
MyMap::value_compare myCompValForMap = mymap.value_comp();


for (int i=0; i<=5; i++) {
  myset.insert(i);
  mymap.insert(make_pair(i, 2*i));
}

//////SET///////

highest1=*myset.rbegin();
std::set<int>::iterator it=myset.begin();
while ( myCompKeyForSet(*it, highest1) ) it++;
std::cout << "\nhighest1 is " << highest1;  // prints 5


highest2 = *myset.rbegin();
it=myset.begin();
while ( myCompValForSet(*it, highest2) ) it++;
std::cout << "\nhighest2 is " << highest2;   // prints 5

//////MAP///////

MyMap::iterator it2 = mymap.begin();
highest3 = mymap.rbegin()->first;
while ( myCompKeyForMap((it2->first), highest3) ) it2++;
std::cout << "\nhighest3 is " << highest3;     // prints 5

std::pair<int,int> highest4 = *mymap.rbegin();    //must be defined as map's `value_type`
it2 = mymap.begin();
while ( myCompValForMap(*(it2), highest4) ) it2++;  // takes `value_type` which is `pair<int, int>` in this case. 
std::cout << "\nhighest4 is " << highest4.second;   // prints 10
```

[Live demo](http://ideone.com/n4QhI9)

As I mentioned the passed arguments to `value_compare` function object must be of type `value_type&`, so I am in a kind of *disagreement* with those saying that these two  `set::key_comp` and `set::value_comp`  are easily compatible across associative containers.